# Crystal associative arrays

Tags: associative-array, crystal-lang

How do you make associative arrays in Crystal ?

In this case I need an array of bools to configure multiple classes.

Ex :

```
arr = ??? # what do i place here to make it work ?
arr[:download] = true
arr[:parse] = true
myClass.new(arr)
```

I do not wish to start gessing were the different values are as time pases ( was download arr[0] or arr[1] ? )

I could use an enum for the array

```
enum Conf
  dowload
  parse
end
```

and then use the values this way

```
arr[Conf::download] = true
arr[Conf::parse] = true
```

but it does not seem as easy to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for a [NamedTuple](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/named_tuple.html):

```
arr = {
  download: true,
  parse: true
}
```

If the keys are at compile time, this is probably the best.
Otherwise you'd need to use a [Hash](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/hash.html), which behaves more like an associative array in a dynamic language.